# Storing bcrypt hashes password in mySQL database.

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, bcrypt

So I'm making a login form in WPF. What I want to happen is that if I add a new user to my database the password gets hashed and stored in my database. This is not working and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. it's not even adding a new user without a hashed password. I would appreciate some help.

Click event to add a new user :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clsDB cdb = new clsDB();
        cdb.Adduser(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("user toegevoegd!");
        this.Close();
    }
```

this is the database class :

```
class clsDB
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Database=loginbcrypt;Uid=root;pwd=");

    public int GetUserid(string un, string pwd)
    {
        int iUserID = 0;
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select UserId from users where Username = @username and Password = @password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", un);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pwd);

        string sUserId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        iUserID = int.Parse(sUserId);
        conn.Close();
        return iUserID;
    }

    public void Adduser(string un, string pwd)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            pwd = pwd + "$Y.N3T~J";
            string salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt();
            string hashToStoreInDatabase = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pwd, salt);
            bool doesPasswordMatch = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(pwd, un);

            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into users (Username, Password) values (@username, @password)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", un);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pwd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're eating the exception. Is it possible that an exception is happening and you're not seeing it?

Comment: You were right :) it was throwing an exception indeed. it throws this exception. BCrypt.Net.SaltParseException: 'Invalid salt version'

Comment: Don't eat those exceptions! haha Lesson learned

Comment: Thank you for your help! I definitely learned my lesson haha.